# Рефакторинг кода формирования дерева из бд

Tags: c#, дерево

У меня есть код получения отделов и сотрудников, надо вывести дерево. В целом код работает, но я бы хотел избавиться от параметра nested без которого я ухожу в бесконечный цикл, как это можно сделать? Сразу оговорюсь что мне не нужны сторонние библиотеки которые умеют работать с деревьями в бд! Если `id = null` значит отдел главный. Циклов в отделах нет. Еще в модели `Department` нет коллекции подотделов, есть только id родителя

```
//nested - костыль для того чтобы не уйти в беск цикл
//если true - то надо доставать по parentId, иначе по id.
private async Task<List<DepartmentTreeItem>> CreateTreeAsync(int? id, bool nested)
{
    var queryableDepartment = (await _departmentRepository.GetQueryableAsync())
        .OrderBy(x => x.Name);

    var employeeQueryable = (await _employeeRepository.GetQueryableAsync())
        .OrderBy(x => x.FullName);

    List<Department> list = new List<Department>();

    if (id != null && !nested)
    {
        list = queryableDepartment
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        list = queryableDepartment
            .Where(x => x.ParentDepartmentId == id)
            .ToList();
    }

    List<DepartmentTreeItem> result = new List<DepartmentTreeItem>();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        List<EmployeeItem> employees = new List<EmployeeItem>();

        employees = employeeQueryable.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == item.Id)
            .Select(x => new EmployeeItem(x.Id, x.FullName))
            .ToList();

        var child = new DepartmentTreeItem
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            Employees = new Collection<EmployeeItem>(employees)
        };
        var manager = child.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.ManagerId);
        if (manager != null)
        {
            child.Employees.Remove(manager);
            child.Manager = manager;
        }
        var items = await CreateTreeAsync(child.Id, true);
        result.Add(child);
        child.Departments = new Collection<DepartmentTreeItem>(items);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Вы бы код сущностей показали или определение таблиц в БД. И какую именно ORM используете? EF? Какой версии?

Comment: Список смежности (adjacency list)? Нужна рекурсия, а EF сам по себе не умеет в неё. Я бы предложил библиотеку linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore. Или пишите сырой SQL с CTE.

Comment: че то сложно. Раз вы все равно из базы всё вычитываете, не проще сразу тогда в память считать все департамнты и всех сотрудников и уже из данных в памяти построить дерево?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov efcore 6, библиотеки не хочу использовать

Comment: @tym32167 да, действительно лучше в память выгрузить и потом только строить, я переписал на более лучшую версию но с рекурсией и постоянным дёрганьем бд, спасибо

Comment: @daoistgu добавил апдейт в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы предложил просто вычитать из БД все данные и по ним сразу всё построить, без рекурсий и прочих сложностей.

Раз вы не привели модели, я их придумал как то так

```cs
class Department
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int ParentDepartmentId;
}

class Employee
{
    public int Id;
    public string FullName;
    public int DepartmentId ;
}

class DepartmentTreeItem
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public List<DepartmentTreeItem> Departments;
    public List<EmployeeItem> Employees;
}

class EmployeeItem
{
    public int Id;
    public string FullName;
}
```

Функция, которая получает данные уже вычитанные из БД и компонует дерево

```cs
private List<DepartmentTreeItem> CreateTree(List<Department> deps, List<Employee> empl)
{
    // делаем список департаментов в дерево
    var treeDepartments = deps.Select(d => new DepartmentTreeItem() {
        Id = d.Id,
        Name = d.Name,
        Employees = empl
            .Where(e => e.DepartmentId == d.Id).Select(e => new EmployeeItem() {Id = e.Id, FullName = e.FullName})
            .ToList()
    }).ToList();
    
    // проставляем департаментам дочерние департаменты
    foreach(var group in deps.GroupBy(d=>d.ParentDepartmentId))
    {
        var tree = treeDepartments.Where(x=>x.Id == group.Key).Single();
        tree.Departments = group
            .Select(x=>treeDepartments.Where(z=>z.Id == x.Id).Single())
            .ToList();
    }
    
    return treeDepartments;
}
```

Этот код вернет все отделы списком. Если вам надо только верхник узлы вернуть, добавьте фильтрацию в конце метода, тут

```
    return treeDepartments; // замените тут на нужную вам фильтрацию
```

Comment: Падает на Single из-за group.Key = null т.к бывают отделы без родительского отдела и не бывает отделов у которых Id == null, по-идее можно в DepartmentTreeItem добавить еще ParentId и сделать if в цикле с GroupBy

Comment: В любом случае спасибо, направили в нужное направление)

Comment: Если добавите `ParentId`, то тогда и `GroupBy` не понадобится )